# How to trim the spaces from first and last of the variable string in Linux?

Tags: linux, sed, variable, whitespace

I am trying to remove white spaces from each variable string. I tried with below command but no use.

```
a="HARISH , SAM"
echo $a|sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//'
```

Comment: your desired output?

Comment: Are there other spaces, that you want to keep (for example between words)?

Comment: What if the person's name is `HARISH , SAM MIDDLENAME`?

Comment: Your string does not have any whitespace at the start or end to trim.  This question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 echo $a | sed -e 's/ //g'
```

you can also try if you have first name and last name

```
echo $a | sed -e 's/ , /,/g'
```

Comment: Above command supports if we have spaces begining, ending and between the string, but if we don't remove between strings like Frist and Second Name then it won't support.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming with "variable string in Linux" you mean a shell variable, why not use shell's "Parameter Expansion", "Pattern Substitution"? Like

```
$ a="HARISH , SAM"
$ echo ${a// }
HARISH,SAM
```

Comment: this would remove the space between the first name and surname.